# When making a Minecraft mod, can't localize names in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm new to Minecraft modding (just started picking up some tutorials today) and
somewhat a beginner to Java (about 7 months experience).

The tutorial I am specifically following is this one right here (and I marked the current relevant time): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhhMoxKSkss&t=335

I'm trying to localize the names of the items so that it shows as "Table" instead of "item.ItemTable.name" in the game. I think the problem is that he is giving the tutorial in Eclipse while I am using IntelliJ Idea. In my head there is some "extra step" I need to do because of this. I launched the project in Eclipse without making any further changes to find that it DOES in fact work in Eclipse. However, I do not prefer that IDE.

Screenshot:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/rOGMFVg.png?1]
Directory tree on left, and "en_US.lang" file opened on the right

When I run the Minecraft client in IntelliJ, the name of the item remains unlocalized, but in Eclipse it does change.

There must be a missing step here that's staring me in the face. I was just hoping someone could point it out to me since I can't find the solution anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in this post: http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php/topic,21354.0.html

In particular:

> If you are using Intellij 14 (which you should) you need to add the following to the end of your build.gradle before importing:
>   sourceSets { main { output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir } }
>   If you don't do that, your assets will not work. (Thanks to Cazzar for this solution)

Problem solved. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.